# Redirecting page mobile not working with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been having problems with a web page and the way the content has been displaying on mobile. To get around this issue I thought it might be better if I direct to another page using javascript. Now there are two html pages, index.html and mobile.html. I have a script tag at the bottom of the index file checking if the screen width is less then 1000px if so do this:

```
<script> 
    if (screen.width <= 1000) {
        window.location.replace = "http://pmoney2.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/mobile.html";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace` is an function you have to call it.

But you are assign it value instead of passing as argument.
Do it like this :-

```
<script> 
    if (screen.width <= 1000) {
        window.location.replace("http://pmoney2.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/mobile.html");
    }
</script>
```

Or you can use `href`

```
<script> 
    if (screen.width <= 1000) {
        window.location.href = "http://pmoney2.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/mobile.html";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Okay thanks, is there anyway I can check what the current url is? if url = www.example.com?

Comment: `window.location.href` will give you current url

Comment: if you check the url in question you will see what i mean, as it dose not work after masking, i should have included in question sorry..

before masking: http://pmoney2.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/mobile.html

after masking: www.kingpmoney.co.uk

Comment: @user10619656 i don't see any error i pasted in console it's working fine. can you tell me what error you're getting ?

Comment: no code errors, just visually.. so that javascript forwarding to the mobile.html dose not work after masking. I might have to create another question for this as it is off topic. I do not think the @media rules are working in the css